# Using a UI to Draw in openGLes for Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I've been doing tons of research on this topic for quite some time now and i think i just need to clear some of it up.Ok i want to make a OpenGL program for android that uses the users interface to update an array of vertices. The user layout consist of a commandline that only accepts float values.
But I need it so the user enters X,Y,Z floats exmaple (X) 1.5,(Y) 2.6024,(Z) 5.92. So far i was able to get one of the values and store it in an array. But i need to do somthing like a vector or array list. EXarray.add(X,y,z).Which does not work but its kinda what i need. So my Question is How Can i get an X,Y,Z value from an edittext and store them in one index so i can update the opengl code through the user interface? Or if anyone would have a better way of doing it i would be very greatful for the help.(sorry im not on my desktop right now or i  would paste the code i do have if it is needed then just let me know and ill update.) 
     Thank you

Comment: If you always want the edittext put it in an xml with glview, if you want it to pop up create a handler to interrupt the glthread and inflate the edittext, should work them ways, I never tried though

Comment: Ok thanks for the info I never thought of having it pop up.

Comment: God luck I'm sure if you look around on this site you will figure out how to accomplish what your trying to do, this site is a great resource

Comment: LOL I know its becuase of this site i got this far. im writing the code for a single float input to an arraylist then to the vertice array then to display. I would rather have the multiple value input tho rather than just asking for one. I know i can do it in C but i would have to pull out some of my old programing stuff tho. and im not so sure the the NDK would accept it so i might read more up on the NDK. if i find out what im looking for ill post it here for everyone.